# Call .c function in cython

Tags: python, c, function, cython

So i'm trying to learn how Cython works and i see a lot of code being created in Cython from c but how do i run a c function from python using Cython. Mind you, i'm very new to python and c code.

### fib.c

```
#include "fib.h"

int fib(int n)
{
   if (n <= 1)
   {
      return n;
   }

   return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

---

### fib.h

```
 int fib (int n);
```

Comment: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/external.html

Comment: So generally this works the same at swig?